# How to handle connection exception on a TcpClient NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I developed a Windows Service running on a server that handles a barcode reader and processes the data it reads.
The problem I have right now is that if the barcode reader loses power or internet connection, I have to restart the service manually.
I would like to know if it is possible to handle a connection Exception to avoid this problem ?

Here are the relevant pieces of code :

```
public void Client()
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, Convert.ToInt32(port));
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    while (true)
    {
        // Data processing
    }
} 

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    IP = args[0];
    port = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);

    Thread thread = new Thread(Client);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: is the service the client or the server? it looks like a client here, which seems a little unusual, but isn't necessarily wrong; but - can't you simply detect the death of the connection and attempt to create a new connection periodically?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, the service is the client. How do I detect the death of connection ? I have a log file that lists all actions performed by the users and exceptions caught but nothing is added to it when the connection is lost.

Comment: a healthy exit is when read/receive returns a non-positive count; an unhealthy exit would be a socket-exception; either way, it ends; note it is also possible to *not detect* a socket death, in which case you'd need some kind of "have I seen anything in [n time interval]?" - ideally combined with a recurring ping on the protocol

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks for your help!